# AEM TagManger method to find all matched tags

Tags: aem

We have AEM TagManager find method to find any matched tag in given Page path

https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-2/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/javadoc/com/day/cq/tagging/TagManager.html#find(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20boolean)

Is there a way to find all matched tags in given Page path?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question appears to be slightly confusing. Do you want the result only if all provided tags match in the content, then you just have to send the param `oneMatchIsEnough` as `false`. If you want to find which tags got matched in the content, then I think you may have to get that list manually.

Comment: Thanks for comment, yes i need to find the all provider tags match, tried with oneMatchIsEnough as false, it worked.